# Why aren't all real numbers equal to one another?

Tags: analysis, fake-proofs

I know, stupid question. But humor me for a sec. First off, we know that all real numbers have two numbers which are infinitely close to them, right? 
That would seem to be, for any given value of x,

> x ± y

where

> y = .000...1

But here's the thing:

> y + .999... = 1

Right?

And, of course, we all know that .999... = 1, so that means that y = 0, right? Which means that all numbers infinitely close to one another, which represents the entirety of the real number line, are equal, right? Something here is screwed up, but for the life of me I can't figure out what.

PS, I wasn't sure what tag to give this, so feel free to edit them.

Comment: What is $0.000\ldots1$ exactly?

Comment: @Alqatrkapa Sorry, I wasn't sure how to write that. Infinite 0's followed by a 1, meant to represent an infinitely small number.

Comment: What you describe is not well-defined as a real number.

Comment: Um, all you are showing seems to be $x=x$. Nothing here implies that any 2 real number are the same.

Comment: @qaphla Could you please explain? I assume you're saying the same thing as Henning Makholm , that y isn't an actual number?

Comment: @Gina, no, it implies that x is equal to the two numbers "right next to it" on the number line, if you will. However, you can see in the answer that such numbers don't exist. So I would agree with you that the "proof" is invalid.

Comment: Yes, essentially, though there are number systems, such as the [hyperreals or nonstandard reals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperreal_number) which have such a number. The real number system that we work with, however, does not.

Comment: @qaphla: Even the nonstandard reals don't have anything that is well-defined by writing "0.000...1" -- for example what would ten times that be? Decimal expansions in the nonstandard world are stranger than that.

Comment: I would agree that there is no "0.000...1", but I was more responding to the OP's description of "an infinitely small number", which certainly appears in the form of infinitesimals in the nonstandard reals.

Comment: BEGIN QUOTE "First off, we know that all real numbers have two numbers which are infinitely close to them, right?" END QUOTE ${}\quad{}$ No.  That is false. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your mistake is in assuming that there is a real number $y=0.000\ldots1$, but actually there is no such thing. The real number system contains no "infinitely small" elements.

It is also wrong when you assert that

> we know that all real numbers have two numbers which are infinitely close to them, right?

Two *different* real numbers are always a *finite* distance from each other.

You can get *as close to your $x$ as you want* without actually hitting it, but that is not the same as saying that you can get "infinitely close" to it.

Comment: Wow, that's an interesting way of looking at it. I suppose "infinitely close" was just a figure of speech my teachers have been using.

Comment: @KnightOfNi: Either that, or they are confused themselves. 200 years ago at the dawn of analysis it was not uncommon to speak of "infinitely small" quantities (Cauchy did it, for example, as a shorthand for limit arguments), but they proved to be difficult to justify in a way that would make sense for students, and today analysis is almost universally taught in terms of explicit limits of _finite_ quantities.

Comment: As an aside to that, it's common for people to say "infinitely close" when what they mean is "arbitrarily close".

Comment: (cue for someone to start shilling non-standard analysis in 3 ... 2 ... 1 ...)

Comment: If you want another example of the difference between "infinitely" and "arbitrarily": You can always find an integer larger than any given integer (arbitrarily large), but there's no integer larger than all others (infinitely large).

Answer (score 1):

"Infinitely many zeroes followed by a 1" is actually not a well-defined decimal numeral.

The places in a decimal numeral are all indexed by integers that denote their location relative to the unit place: e.g. the hundred's place has index $2$ and the thousandth's place has index $-3$.

If you have infinitely many zeroes to the right of the decimal point, that means every place whose index is a negative integer has to be a zero: so there aren't any places left to put a $1$!

One can create a numeral system that would allow numerals like the one you wrote, but there isn't a good number system for them to correspond to. e.g. what would $0.\overline{0}5 + 0.\overline{0}5$ be?